# Excel VBA - hide rows on sheet load

Tags: excel, vba

In the interest of clarity, I've wiped the original question and am re-posting.

Scenario:

Source workbook has multiple pages, front page of book has a query/extract function to create a new book with some pre-entered data using a template from one of the sheets in the source book.

Requirements:

Phase 1: Extract function needs to set all rows beyond row 6 as hidden where the data in column A = HC.

First (and so far working) draft of that code as follows:

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim wbkOriginal As Workbook
    Set wbkOriginal = ActiveWorkbook

    'sets site name and site ID into the estate page to be extracted
    Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("E6")
    Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Range("D3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("N6")
    Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Range("F3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("K6")

    'hiding all rows that being with HC apart from row 6 which is the starting row
    'code to be added to the individual estate sheets to unhide each row after status column filled
    'on a row by row basis - as the hiding is for HC rows only, the section headers will remain visible
    'may have to code around that on the sheet itself
    BeginRow = 7
    EndRow = 300
    ChkCol = 1

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value Like "HC" Then
            Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next RowCnt

    ' copies sheet name from combo box into new document, saves it with site name,
    ' site id and current date into user profile desktop folder for ease of access
    ' with new HEAT, worth investigating if sheet can be saved directly to a call ID folder?
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value)
        .Copy
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
                "C:\temp\" _
                & .Cells(3, 2).Text _
                & " " _
                & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY") _
                & ".xlsm", _
                xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, , , , False
        End With

    'code to close the original workbook to prevent accidental changes etc
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbkOriginal.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```

Phase 2: Each row that starts with HC, has a drop down in column E. That drop down has 3 options, 'Complete' 'Incomplete' and 'Not Required'

Task: When the user selects and clicks on an entry, the sheet needs to do the following

- Unhide the next row
- Enter the current windows username into column I
- Enter the current time into column J

Prototype code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim ChangedCell As Object
Dim lRow As Long

       For Each ChangedCell In Target
       If ChangedCell.Column = 5 And ChangedCell <> "" Then
            lRow = ChangedCell.Row + 1
                lRow.Hidden = False
                Cells(lRow, 8) = Environ("USERNAME")
                Cells(lRow, 9) = "HH:MM"
            End If
       Next
End Sub
```

Problem:

Compile error: Invalid Qualifier, referring to the lRow.Hidden = False line,

Tried to declare it as an object instead, thinking that would allow me to spec it that way instead, but no joy to be had.

As ever, any guidance from the community would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks.

Rob.

Comment: To get you started, you do not need to loop through each row to check for "HC" in Col A. Simply use Autofilter and hide the rows in one go. Secondly for Col E, use the `Worksheet_Change` event. Give it a try and if you are still stuck then post the code that you tried and then we will take it from there

Comment: The autofilter would be fine if I was trusting to the users to do it manually, but as I don't, that was the reason for getting some code in there - there's a process management issue going on, hence needing to force users into doing one step at a time, and acknowledging each step when done.

Comment: I meant autofilter by code...

Comment: Well what I've got now on the extract button on the front page is this (note: code does not include extraction process itself)

<code>BeginRow = 7
EndRow = 300
ChkCol = 1
For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
    If Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value Like "HC" Then
        Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
    End If
Next RowCnt</code>

Comment: OK, I apparently fail at using mini-markdown, and can't get it to display in code form :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Extract()

    Dim wbkOriginal As Workbook
    Set wbkOriginal = ActiveWorkbook

    'sets site name and site ID into the estate page to be extracted
    Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("E6")
    Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Range("D3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("N6")
    Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Range("F3").Value = Worksheets("front page").Range("K6")

    'hiding all rows that being with HC apart from row 6 which is the starting row
    'code to be added to the individual estate sheets to unhide each row after status column filled
    'on a row by row basis - as the hiding is for HC rows only, the section headers will remain visible
    'may have to code around that on the sheet itself
    BeginRow = 7
    EndRow = 300
    ChkCol = 1

    For RowCnt = BeginRow To EndRow
        If Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).Value <> "" Then
            Worksheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value).Cells(RowCnt, ChkCol).EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next RowCnt

    ' copies sheet name from combo box into new document, saves it with site name,
    ' site id and current date into user profile desktop folder for ease of access
    ' with new HEAT, worth investigating if sheet can be saved directly to a call ID folder?
        With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(Sheet11.CmbSheet.Value)
        .Copy
                ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
                "C:\temp\" _
                & .Cells(3, 2).Text _
                & " " _
                & Format(Now(), "DD-MM-YY") _
                & ".xlsm", _
                xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, , , , False
        End With

    'code to close the original workbook to prevent accidental changes etc
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wbkOriginal.Close
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    End Sub
```